# translating normal member variables to static member variables results in problems

Tags: c++, static-members

I used to have a normal member variable, which was initialized in the constructors as following:

```
ResourceSaveFunctions[OBJECTS_IDENT] = NULL;
ResourceSaveFunctions[SPRITES_IDENT] = &GMProject::SaveSprite;
ResourceSaveFunctions[SOUNDS_IDENT] = &GMProject::SaveSound;
ResourceSaveFunctions[BACKGROUNDS_IDENT] = &GMProject::SaveBackground;
ResourceSaveFunctions[PATHS_IDENT] = NULL;
ResourceSaveFunctions[SCRIPTS_IDENT] = NULL;
ResourceSaveFunctions[FONTS_IDENT] = NULL;
ResourceSaveFunctions[TIMELINES_IDENT] = NULL;
ResourceSaveFunctions[ROOMS_IDENT] = NULL;
ResourceSaveFunctions["extension"] = &GMProject::SaveExtension;
ResourceSaveFunctions[INCLUDES_IDENT] = NULL;
ResourceSaveFunctions[TRIGGERS_IDENT] = NULL;
```

The variable is a map with as key strings, and as data member-function-pointers. This worked perfectly fine. However as said I believe this map should be static (?) - the reason for the map is just to identify what the program should do during reading of a file. - NULL meaning "do nothing special".

So I changed it to the following:

```
std::map<std::string, GMProject::GMProjectMemFn> GMProject::ResourceSaveFunctions_INIT() {
    std::map<std::string, GMProjectMemFn> tmp;
    tmp.insert(std::make_pair(OBJECTS_IDENT,NULL));
    tmp.insert(std::make_pair(SPRITES_IDENT, &GMProject::SaveSprite));
    tmp.insert(std::make_pair(SOUNDS_IDENT, &GMProject::SaveSound));
    tmp.insert(std::make_pair(BACKGROUNDS_IDENT, &GMProject::SaveBackground));
    tmp.insert(std::make_pair(PATHS_IDENT, NULL));
    tmp.insert(std::make_pair(SCRIPTS_IDENT, NULL));
    tmp.insert(std::make_pair(FONTS_IDENT, NULL));
    tmp.insert(std::make_pair(TIMELINES_IDENT, NULL));
    tmp.insert(std::make_pair(ROOMS_IDENT, NULL));
    tmp.insert(std::make_pair("extension", &GMProject::SaveExtension));
    tmp.insert(std::make_pair(INCLUDES_IDENT, NULL));
    tmp.insert(std::make_pair(TRIGGERS_IDENT, NULL));
    return tmp;
}
const std::map<std::string, GMProject::GMProjectMemFn> GMProject::ResourceSaveFunctions(GMProject::ResourceSaveFunctions_INIT());
```

Where those things are declared in the header:

```
static const std::map<std::string, GMProjectMemFn> ResourceSaveFunctions;
static std::map<std::string, GMProjectMemFn> ResourceSaveFunctions_INIT();
```

Now compiling suddenly brings up a lot of errors.

> 1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(163): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'GMProject::GMProjectMemFn '

Which is about the conversion of NULL. However shouldn't this be just possible? Why is this not possible (yet in the previous method it was)?
Should I use an explicit cast here?

EDIT:
GMProjectMemFn defined as following:

```
typedef void (GMProject::*GMProjectMemFn)(const pTree&) const;
```

pTree being a container.

Comment: What is the definition of `GMProjectMemFn`?

Comment: Are you implementing virtual tables yourself?  I am not clear on what your big map o' member function pointers is needed for...it looks like something from a C program.

Comment: @Kerrek_SB "partially" - using visual studio 2010 - but no I can't use initializer lists.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Well this is used for something like "xml files" - during saving normally a standard approach can be used - which consists of reading the xml value, which contains a file location and then copying that file. However as I don't have control over the format of the xml files, in some specific cases something extra should occur. For these cases I wrote a seperate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::make_pair` creates a `pair<T1, T2>` where the types `T1` and `T2` are deduced implicitly from the types of the arguments. `NULL` expands to `0` (or `0L`) so in your case `make_pair` returns a `pair<string, int>` (or a `pair<string, long>`).

You then try passing that `pair<string, int>` to `map<string, GMProject::GMProjectMemFn>::insert()` but this expects a `pair<string, GMProjectMemFn>`.

`std::pair` has a general copy constructor which will attempt implicit conversion of each member of the pair:

```
template <class U, class V>
    pair (const pair<U,V> &p) : first(p.first), second(p.second) { }
```

but in your case this requires converting a `const int&` to a pointer, which is not permitted.

In your original case you were directly converting `NULL` into a pointer, which is well defined.

Explicitly typing your `pair` should fix this:

```
tmp.insert(std::pair<std::string, GMProject::GMProjectMemFn>(TIMELINES_IDENT, NULL));
```

Comment: But doesn't `std::pair` have a non-`explicit` generalized copy constructor taking an arbitrarily typed `std::pair` and doing member-wise conversion? So a `pair<string,int>` should indeed be convertible to a `pair<string,GMProjectMemFn>` as long as `int` is convertible to `GMProjectMemFn`.

Comment: Yes, you're completely right. The _real_ problem is that a `int const&` can't be implicitly cast to a pointer. I'll correct my answer. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

ah. NULL is probably defined only as literal 0, `make_pair` deduces this to integer, and `pair<int,int>` is not convertible to `pair<int,GMProjectMemFn>`. It worked with assignment through operator[] because (I guess) of implicit conversion from 0 to `GMProjectMemFn`.

So, try writing `make_pair(PATHS_IDENT, (GMProjectMemFn)0)`.